# After I set currentColor in my constructor it changes back to its original value when paintComponent is called

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have been looking at this one for a while and it doesn't make sense. When I start my program, I set the background color of a grid of rectangles to a specific color using the SetupLawn call from my main function in a different file. That part works fine. Then when I try to change the color later by calling the SetupLawn function again with a new color it doesn't change. I put prints in the SetupLawn function and the color I am passing is getting there correctly but as soon as paintComponent gets called the value of currentColor is back to being what it was originally. I verified this with a debug print as well.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Lawn
{
    public static class SetupLawn extends JPanel
    {
        private List<Point> lawn;
        Color currentColor;

        public SetupLawn(Color color)
        {
            lawn = new ArrayList<>(25);
            currentColor = color;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (Point cell : lawn)
            {
                int cellX = cell.x;
                int cellY = cell.y;
                g.setColor(currentColor);
                g.fillRect(cellX, cellY, 50, 50);
            }

            //Set grid color and draw border
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRect(10, 10, 800, 500);

            for (int i = 10; i <= 800; i += 50)
            {
                g.drawLine(i, 10, i, 510);
            }

            for (int i = 10; i <= 500; i += 50)
            {
                g.drawLine(10, i, 810, i);
            }

            for (int i = 60; i <= 750; i += 50)
            {
                for (int j =60; j <= 450; j += 50)
                {
                    lawn.add(new Point(i, j));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the way I was calling it.

```
Lawn.SetupLawn lawn = new Lawn.SetupLawn(spring);
```

I can see now why this method was not a good idea. It was really late at night when I was working on this and Java is not a strong language for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "calling the SetupLawn function again"?  `SetUpLawn` is a class.  Do you mean you're creating a second instance of it?  And how are you showing the panel?

Comment: As @DavidWallace already hinted at, how does your calling code look like? In this code I can just suggest to add a setter for the color. And why are you using a nested class with the outer class `Lawn` doing nothing?

Comment: It is a work in progress. I think at one point I had other functions inside of lawn but I was having "non-static fields cannot be referenced from a static context" errors. That was what I originally tried to do was create a setColor function inside of Lawn. That is kinda what I am working on now, learning about that error and trying everything that way. I just thought it was unusual that a value I had just set and printed changed to something else after paintComponent.

Comment: Edited original to answer your questions.

Comment: Is this solved or do you still need help?

Comment: My apologies. School stole my attention and I forgot to respond. I ended up rewriting the entire class so it would make more sense. The original was poorly written in the first place. I am assuming the issue was that every time I called the constructor I was making a new instance. Well I don't assume that part I know that part was true. The part I am assuming is that when paintComponent was called, it was still looking at the original instance every time. Does that sound right?